# Is it possible to draw multiple objects in webgl without using a loop?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to learn webgl and saw some post where people used loops to draw multiple objects.

But as i was working with this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Creating_3D_objects_using_WebGL

And i wondered if it is possible to create multiple objects without using loops.

for eg. like cube has multiple faces, can we draw in such a way so that i can draw two cubes side-by-side without using a loop?

Comment: Yes you can. Just use the same logic twice with the correct values for each cube. Though, a loop is typically the way to go when doing the same thing over and over with slight variation..

Comment: @RichardBarker actually when _drawing_ objects through a graphics api you want to avoid loops as much as possible and batch as much as you can together in a single draw call.